# Regular expression to find the exact match for <img> tag in a string.- JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use a regex to identify for any  tag in a string. I have dynamic data that can include records like:

```
str1= "TT-DD-11-AZR"&gt;&lt;img src=x onerror=alert(1)&gt;"
str2 = "RR-DD-22-AZR"&gt;&lt;img src=http://localhost/ma.php&gt;"
```

I'm using Regex the following way:

```
function regex() {
    let str1= "TT-DD-11-AZR"&gt;&lt;img src=x onerror=alert(1)&gt;"
    let regex = new RegExp("<img([\w\W]+?)/>", "g");
    const match = regex.exec(str1);
if (match) { //this comes as null
   return match;
}
}
```

I also tried:

```
regex= "/src=([^\\\"]+)/"
```

Both return null. Any idea what could I identify the <img src ? tag inside a string.

Thanks

Comment: Why would `<` in your Regex match `&lt;` in your input string?

Comment: ok may be not, but you know what would match then? My regex is def not correct and hence its not returning the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to match against `<>` and not `&lt;&gt;`. In addition, back slashes must be escaped within the [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Therefore:

```js
function regex() {
    let str1= "TT-DD-11-AZR\"&gt;&lt;img src=x onerror=alert(1)&gt;"
    let regex = new RegExp("&lt;img([\\w\\W]+?)&gt;", "g");
    const match = regex.exec(str1);
if (match) { //this comes as null
   return match;
}
}

console.log(regex())
```